# How can I merge audio and video stream with delay

Tags: audio, video, video-encoding, matroska

Let's say I have `audio.m4a` and `video.m2v` and the video stream starts approx. 13 sec with the expected sound output but my audio.m4a immediately.

So I have to merge it with a delay! I tried already this command:

```
mkvmerge video.m2v audio.m4a -o output.mkv --sync 1:13000
```

but no effect.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Your command structure is out of sequence; and, your particular audio would be track 0 of itself, not track 1.

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv video.m2v -y 0:+13000 audio.m4a
```